# How to set the map object into Cypress result json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I'm using cypress runner to execute the spec file and return the result as like below.

**Runner.js:**

```
const cypress = require('cypress');
const param = require("./cypress/support/Param");

async function testRunner(fixture) {
    return cypress.run({
      config: {
      },
      env: {
        testcaseID: `${fixture}`,
      },
      spec: './cypress/integration/' + `${param.getSpec()}` + ".spec.js",
    });
  }
```

**Spec file:**

```
let map = new Map();

describe("How to add map values in the cypress result.json",() =>{

    const baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";

    const testData = Cypress.env('fixture')

    beforeEach("",()=>{

        cy.visit(baseUrl);
    });

    it("Test Case1: Search the keyword", function () {
            cy.xpath("//input[@name='q']").type(testData.searchKeyword);
            map.set("UserInput",testData.searchKeyword); //It's just sample
            cy.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']").click();
            map.set("customMessage","test"); //It's just sample but actual usecase is different
            cy.get("//ul/li[2]").should("be.visible");
    });

});
```

using the below lines to get the result in the main runner:

```
result = await testRunner(dataSet[i]);
                    if (result.runs[0].stats.failures === 1) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
```

The above code is working fine and I can able to get the result.json which contains whether the test case is pass/failed. But In addition I just want to add few more runtime values which I stored in the Map and wanna add those in the Cypress.run return result.

Can someone please suggest me the optimized way to handle this? How can I get some runtime values which is available inside the map and that will be returned along with cypress run result.

Thanks in advance.

**Updated:**

I just created a Map() variable and calling that variable by using the getter and setter but still no luck.

```
var EnumPojo = {
    
    LISTENER: new Map(),

    get listener()
    {
        return this.LISTENER;
    },

    set listener(value)
    {
        return this.listener =value;
    };

}
```

**Called the above map into script:**

```
const runtimeValues = require("../../EnumPojo.js");

 describe("How to add map values in the cypress result.json",() =>{
    
        const baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
    
        const testData = Cypress.env('fixture')
    
        beforeEach("",()=>{
    
            cy.visit(baseUrl);
        });
    
        it("Test Case1: Search the keyword", function () {
                cy.xpath("//input[@name='q']").type(testData.searchKeyword);
                runtimeValues.LISTENER.set("UserInput",testData.searchKeyword); //It's just sample
                cy.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']").click();
                runtimeValues.LISTENER.set("customMessage","test"); //It's just sample but actual usecase is different
                cy.get("//ul/li[2]").should("be.visible");
        });
    
    });
```

**Runner:**

```
 const runtimeValues = require("../../EnumPojo.js");

 result = await testRunner(dataSet[i]);
                        if (result.runs[0].stats.failures === 1) {
                            console.log(result);
                            console.log(runtimeValues.LISTENER);
                        }
```

Output:
Map{0}

Answer (score 0):

In test, save the map under fixtures

```js
it('my-test', function () {

  ...
  cy.fixture('map.json').then(mapData => {
    mapData['my-test'] = JSON.stringify(map)  // use unique key for this test
    cy.writeFile('./fixtures/map.json', JSON.stringify(mapData))
  })
})
```

In runner,

```js
const fs = require('fs')

cypress.run({...})
  .then(result => {
    const mapData = fs.readFileSync('./cypress/fixtures/map.json')  // adjust path to where script is
    /*
      mapData is {
        'my-test': { ...data here },
        'other-test': { ...data here },
      }
    */   
   })
```

BUT Javascript `Map` may not serialize correctly, best to convert to object before saving.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I have a many test that associated with a suite, and Is there any other way to append some custom variable as key value pair in the result of cypress runner?

Comment: Your runner code looks like it does one spec at time, but if you want extra data per multiple test, I will give an amendment.